# передача данных между экранами

Tags: flutter, dart

На главном экране я ввожу в поле ввода текст, нажимаю на кнопку, происходит переход на второй экран, происходит передача данных и отображение на втором экране. 
Когда я все делаю то же самое но на втором экране, при переходе на первый экран, данные не переносятся. 
Первый способ

```
Navigator.pop(context, _MyHomePageState(data: _controller.text));
```

Второй способ

```
Navigator.push(
 context,
 //MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Two())
 MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => _MyHomePageState(data: _controller.text,))
).then((value) {
 _controller.text = ''; //очистка поля ввода
});
```

Ошибка в

```
_MyHomePageState(data: _controller.text,)
```

Далее, полный код и скриншоты
**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   title: 'Name App',
   theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
   ),
   home: MyHomePage(),
  );
 }
}
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState(data: null);
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

 //это будет передаваться в другой экран
 TextEditingController _controller;

 //это будет передано с другого экрана
 String data;

 _MyHomePageState ({@required this.data});

 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();

  _controller = TextEditingController();
  data = '';

 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
  super.dispose();
 }

 void _f1() {
  setState(() {
  });
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
   appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Main screen'),
   ),
   body: Stack(
    children: [
     Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: Padding(
       padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
       child: TextField(
        controller: _controller,
        cursorColor: Colors.pink,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
         border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
          borderSide: BorderSide()
         ),
        ),
       ),
      ),
     ),
     Align(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Text(
       (data == null) ? '' : data,
       style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 46.0,
        color: Colors.pink
       ),
      ),
     ),
     Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: Container(
       width: double.infinity,
       margin: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
       child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {
         Navigator.push(
          context,
          //MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Two())
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Two(data: _controller.text,))
         ).then((value) {
          _controller.text = ''; //очистка поля ввода
         });
        },
        splashColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
        ),
        child: Text(
         'Go to Two',
         style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.deepPurple,
          fontSize: 20.0,
         ),
        ),
       ),
      ),
     ),
    ],
   ),
  );
 }

}

class Two extends StatelessWidget {

 //это будет передаваться в другой экран
 TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

 //это будет передаваться в другой экран
 String data;

 Two({Key key, @required this.data}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
   appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Two screen'),
   ),
   body: Stack(
    children: [
     Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: Padding(
       padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
       child: TextField(
        controller: _controller,
        cursorColor: Colors.pink,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
         border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
          borderSide: BorderSide()
         ),
        ),
       ),
      ),
     ),
     Align(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Text(
       (data == null) ? '' : data,
       style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 46.0,
        color: Colors.blue
       ),
      ),
     ),
     Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: Container(
       width: double.infinity,
       margin: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
       child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {
         //1 способ ошибки нет, но данные не выводятся
         Navigator.pop(context, _MyHomePageState(data: _controller.text));

         //2 способ ошибка в _MyHomePageState(data: _controller.text,)
         /*Navigator.push(
          context,
          //MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Two())
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => _MyHomePageState(data: _controller.text,))
         ).then((value) {
          _controller.text = ''; //очистка поля ввода
         });*/

        },
        splashColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
        ),
        child: Text(
         'Go to Main',
         style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.deepPurple,
          fontSize: 20.0,
         ),
        ),
       ),
      ),
     ),
    ],
   ),
  );
 }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вызов конструктора **_MyHomePageState** должен выполняться только один раз, при создании виджета **_MyHomePage**, все остальные вызовы не имеют смысла, т.к. новые экземпляры просто повисают в воздухе. Параметр **data** из конструктора удалил - для корневого виджета он бесполезен.

При возврате со второй страницы на первую передавайте только сами данные, в данном случае это содержимое **_controller.text**. Если нужно вернуть сразу несколько значений, то можно создать свой класс и возвращать его экземпляр, но в более-менее серьезных проектах стоит воспользоваться глобальным хранилищем состояния, например *BLOC*.

Сама обработка полученного со второй страницы значения должна сопровождаться вызовом **setState**, иначе главная страница будет отображать старые данные.

Вот основные изменения вашего кода в diff-формате:

```
--- a/lib/main.dart
+++ b/lib/main.dart
@@ -18,7 +18,7 @@ class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 
 class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
-  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState(data: null);
+  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
 }
 
 class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
@@ -28,8 +28,6 @@ class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
   //это будет передано с другого экрана
   String data;
 
-  _MyHomePageState({@required this.data});
-
   @override
   void initState() {
     super.initState();
@@ -91,6 +89,9 @@ class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
                                 data: _controller.text,
                               ))).then((value) {
                     _controller.text = ''; //очистка поля ввода
+                    setState(() {
+                      data = value;
+                    });
                   });
                 },
                 splashColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5),
@@ -113,10 +114,10 @@ class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 
 class Two extends StatelessWidget {
   //это будет передаваться в другой экран
-  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
+  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
 
   //это будет передаваться в другой экран
-  String data;
+  final String data;
 
   Two({Key key, @required this.data}) : super(key: key);
 
@@ -157,7 +158,7 @@ class Two extends StatelessWidget {
               child: RaisedButton(
                 onPressed: () {
                   //1 способ ошибки нет, но данные не выводятся
-                  Navigator.pop(context, _MyHomePageState(data: _controller.text));
+                  Navigator.pop(context, _controller.text);
 
--
```

Comment: Уважаемый Spatz, спасибо Вам огромное. НО, Вы бы еще зашифровали код с помощью машины тьюринга, вообще ничего не понятно. Неужели просто нельзя было скопировать файл, закоментировать где я ошибся, а рядом написать правильный код. Эти плюсы, минусы, вот это @@ -91,6 +89,9 @@. Зачем так все усложнять, не понимаю.

Comment: @Anton рано или поздно, но с diff-форматом придется познакомиться. С ним можно смотреть что вы делали на прошлой неделе, например (ну это конечно если вы пользуетесь git-ом или аналогом). Удачи! ;)